# How to get files from clients local directory?

Tags: node.js, web

I want to create an upload form that will send an image to my hosted server, but i can't find a clear answer on how node.js interacts with the clients side of things.

A lot of the file upload examples I can find use a simple fs get from the temp directory. But when I run code on my server that looks like this:

```
    var os = require('os');
    var ostemp = os.tmpDir();
    console.log( "Temp directory", ostemp );
```

It obviously returns a server filepath to the logs when I visit, not my windows temp. Makes sense as node.js is purely server side, so how is it usually done?

EDIT:
I think a related problem I'm having is that my host (GANDI) only allows SFTP file transfer, which might be preventing me from sending files via a form submit thing, though I might be confused about that too. Either way I'd appreciate being set straight...